# common google map api key for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am building an mobile application in android 2.2 along with the another developer in the team. I am using mapview for it. Me and the other developer has got different keys. Now, my question is what would be the key when the application is uploaded in the android market? Can there be any common api key?

Sorry, just a bit confused abt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API you have to specify depends on the certificate you use to sign your application.

In the Android SDK, a self-signed certificate is generated upon installation and this "developer" certificate is used to deploy the application in the emulator. The key you are using is based on this one.

Since your felow developer has another installation of the SDK, he has another certificate. Different certificate means different key, so you don't have the same.

When deploying an app on the market, you are not allowed to use a "developer" certificate. You have to use a different one. The Android Market documentation explains you that part in details before deploying your first app. A new Google Maps API has to be generated for this certificate, and you have to build and package your app with this key.

And no, there is no generic, (or "common") key that you can use everywhere. You have to ask for a new one for each certificate you have.